# Variable being undefined in data() in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, nuxt.js

For some reason this was giving me trouble this morning, and I just couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work.

I have a variable 'applications' set equal to the data returned by my axios call. I want to include 'applications.name' as a field in my data() to send as a form. However when I try this, Vue gives me an error saying 'Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'.

{{applicants.name}} and {{applicants.role}} are working in the template, so I'm not just getting empty data

Also another thing, data() doesn't seem to recognize my 'this.loggedInUser.id' field either for some reason. (I've imported both Vuex and mapGetters)

Appreciate the help! :)

```
async asyncData({ $axios, params }) {
    try {
      let applicants = await $axios.$get(`/api/v1/apps/${params.id}/`);
      return { applicants };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return { applicants: [] };
    }
  },
data() {
    return {
      applicants: [],
      application: {
        name: this.applicants.name,
        status: null,
        company: null,
        role: this.applicants.role
        // user: this.loggedInUser.id

      }
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass `this` as parameter to the data property function:

```
data(vm) { //refers to this keyword
    return {
      applicants: [],
      application: {
        name: vm.applicants.name,
        status: null,
        company: null,
        role: vm.applicants.role
        // user:vm.loggedInUser.id

      }
    };
  }
```

or make `application` as a computed property :

```
data() {
    return {
      applicants: [],
    
    };
  }
,
computed:{
    application(){
        return {
        name: this.applicants.name,
        status: null,
        company: null,
        role: this.applicants.role
        // user: this.loggedInUser.id

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: The computed property solution worked for me, would you mind just explaining why variables can also be stored in Computed? I can only find docs on it showing methods that manipulate variables in data(). Thanks!

Comment: if that data depends on other data it should be stored as computed property, if it doesn't it could be declared in data option

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that when the data is initialized, the values **applicants.name** and **loggedInUser.id** do not exist. Try changing the data like this

```
data() {
    return {
        applicants: { name: '' },
        application: {
            name: this.applicants.name,
        },
        loggedInUser: { id: '' }
    };
}
```